# Finding the rank of the Matrix $M$ for the different values of $\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, matrix-rank

Let's have $\
  M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   1 & \alpha & -1 & 2 \\
   2 & -1 & \alpha & 5 \\
   1 & 10 & -6 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$.

Using Gaussian elimination I've come to have the next matrix
 $\
  M'=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{ccccc}
   1 & \alpha & -1 & 2 \\
   0 & 1 & \frac{-5}{10- \alpha} & \frac{-1}{10 - \alpha} \\
   0 &  0 & \frac{-5(1+2\alpha)}{10- \alpha}+\alpha +2 & 1 \\
  \end{array} } \right]$

So:

- $\alpha \neq 10$
- $\frac{-5(1+2\alpha)}{10- \alpha}+\alpha +2 = 1$ and then i calculate the values of $\alpha$

Is it ok what I did? Is the rank always going to be 3 no matter the value of $\alpha \neq 10$ ? What if $\alpha = 10$ ?

Since it is not a square matrix this is the only way to find out the rank, or is there another way?

Comment: If $\alpha=10$ you cannot divide a row by $10-\alpha$, so you should study the case $\alpha=10$ before doing that row operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good strategy for these problems is to do as many operations as you can without dividing by an expression involving a variable.

In particular, I find:
$$
\pmatrix{
 1 & \alpha & -1 & 2 \\
   2 & -1 & \alpha & 5 \\
   1 & 10 & -6 & 1 \\
} \to
\pmatrix{
 1 & \alpha & -1 & 2 \\
   0 & -1 - 2\alpha & 2+\alpha & 1 \\
   0 & 10-\alpha & -5 & -1 \\
}
$$
The rank of this matrix is always at least $2$, since the first and last rows are linearly independent.  We can only have rank exactly two if the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{-1-2\alpha & 2+\alpha & 1\\
10-\alpha & -5 & -1}
$$
has rank $1$.  That is, we can only achieve rank $2$ if the first and second columns are multiples of the third.  In other words, we must have
$$
-(-1-2\alpha) = 10 - \alpha \implies \alpha = 3\\
(-(-5)) = 2 + \alpha \implies \alpha = 3
$$
So indeed, when $\alpha = 3$, the matrix has rank $2$.  In all other cases, the matrix has rank $3$.

---

A more computational approach is to note that permuting the columns (or more generally "applying column operations") doesn't change the rank.  So, we can have
$$
\pmatrix{
 1 & \alpha & -1 & 2 \\
   2 & -1 & \alpha & 5 \\
   1 & 10 & -6 & 1 \\
} \to
\pmatrix{
 1 & \alpha & -1 & 2 \\
   0 & -1 - 2\alpha & 2+\alpha & 1 \\
   0 & 10-\alpha & -5 & -1 \\
}
\\ \to 
\pmatrix{
 1 &2 & \alpha & -1  \\
   0 &1 & -1 - 2\alpha & 2+\alpha \\
   0 & -1 & 10-\alpha & -5 \\
}
\\ \to 
\pmatrix{
 1 &2 & \alpha & -1  \\
   0 &1 & -1 - 2\alpha & 2+\alpha \\
   0 & 0 & 9-3\alpha & -3 + \alpha \\
}
$$
It is clear that this matrix will have full rank whenever $\alpha \neq 3$, and rank $2$ when $\alpha = 3$.

Comment: You said: "since the first and last rows are linearly independent", the rank is at least 2. I understand that the first row can not be expressed as a linear combination of the second and third row, but that would mean that you know that at least the first row wont be 0, so the rank will be at least 1. What about the other rows? They also can not be expressed as a linear combination of the others? Thanks

Comment: @Karl it was enough to note that the first and last rows are non-zero, and that the last row is not a multiple of the first.  I do not understand your last 3 sentences.

Comment: Yes, since i know that the rank of a matrix is eq to the amount of linearly independent rows. I though that would mean vector(rows) that will be non 0 can not be expressed as a linear combination of the other vectors(rows). That is true for the first row. I'm saying that i dont know if the second or the third rows can or not be expressed as a combination of the other rows. I know that the first and last are linearly independent, but i thought that *all* the vectors had  to be. I'm expressing myself very poorly, but i hope you understand what i am trying to say here.

Comment: @Karl let $R_1,R_2,R_3$ denote the rows of our matrix.  The question of whether the rows are linearly independent is the question of whether
$$
c_1 R_1 + c_2 R_3 + c_3 R_3 = 0
$$
implies that $c_1 = c_2 = c_3 = 0$.  In our reduced matrix, we see that the first entry of $c_1 R_1 + c_2 R_2 + c_3 R_3$ is just $c_1$, so we must have $c_1 = 0$.  We therefore conclude that our rows will be linearly independent if and only if there is no non-zero solution to
$$
c_2 R_2 + c_3 R_3 = 0
$$
That is, it is enough to only think of the last two rows in the final step.

Comment: I mean, you said it is enough to note that the last row is not a multiple of the first. What i'm saying is that the last row ( or any row in that case), should not multiple of the second and first, meaning, should not be a linear combination of the other rows.

Comment: @Karl in order for the rank to be $1$, every row would have to be a multiple of the first